# caliburn micro tutorial problem

Tags: silverlight, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I'm just starting the tutorial for CM and up to the last example [here](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions&referringTitle=Documentation). I wanted to get a better feel for what I can do with CM, so I did some one thing I would normally do in a wpf project, make a folder for Views and a folder for ViewModels. Conventions should still find everything, right?

All of the other examples work great this way, but between being ignorant about both CM and how to debug silverlight, I'm at a loss to explain what appears to be a data context issue - nothing but the add button displays.

Can someone spot the problem?

Cheers,
Berryl

## VM

```
[Export(typeof(IShell))]
public class ShellWithCompositionViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public BindableCollection<Model> Items { get; private set; }

    public ShellWithCompositionViewModel() {
        Items = new BindableCollection<Model>
                {
                    new Model {Id = Guid.NewGuid()},
                    new Model {Id = Guid.NewGuid()},
                    new Model {Id = Guid.NewGuid()},
                    new Model {Id = Guid.NewGuid()}
                };
    }

    public void Add() { Items.Add(new Model {Id = Guid.NewGuid()}); }

    public void Remove(Model child) { Items.Remove(child); }
}
```

## VIEW

```
<UserControl x:Class="Caliburn.Micro.Hello.Views.ShellWithCompositionView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
         >
<StackPanel>

    <ItemsControl x:Name="Items">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Content="Remove" cal:Message.Attach="Remove($dataContext)" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <Button Content="Add" cal:Message.Attach="Add" />

</StackPanel>
```

## BOOT

```
namespace Caliburn.Micro.Hello
{
    //public class HelloBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<ShellViewModel> { }
    //public class HelloBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<ShellWithParametersViewModel> { }
    public class HelloBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<ShellWithCompositionView> { }
}
```

## The FIX

```
// left off the model the 1st time (caps not needed!)
public class HelloBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<ShellWithCompositionViewMODEL> { }
```

Comment: Duh... this is actually an easy one and definitely not a CM issue. The clue being in the Bootstrapper, if anyone wants some quick answer points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your Bootstrapper references the View rather than the ViewModel. You should change it to this:

```
public class HelloBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<IShell> { }
```

Also, make sure that you implement the IShell interface on ShellWithCompositionViewModel in addition to applying the export attribute.

Comment: Yep - didn't think I'd have to wait for *you* to scoop up the ten points though :--)

Comment: Hang on, is that the markup omitting the brackets or did you really mean it to read with no generic type??? Should be HelloBootstrapper : Bootstrapper{{ShellWithCompositionView}} { } as per edited question. Cheers